# Jacobian of trace of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

I would like to compute the following Jacobian with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{\partial trace[A(x)A(x)^{T}]}{\partial x}$$

where $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. The result should be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. So far I have something like:

$$\frac{\partial trace[A(x)A(x)^{T}]}{\partial x} \\
= \frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial trace[A(x)A(x)^{T}]}{\partial A(x)} \\
= \frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x} \cdot 2A(x)$$

But the dimensions aren't working out to give a result in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. I'm definitely missing something. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you understand the meaning of differentiating a function by something that isn't a scalar. What you wrote is "basically correct", but the correct interpretation of $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}$ is not something you probably think is.

I don't think your notation $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}$ makes a lot of sense. The most "sane" interpretation of it might be the operator taking $x$ and then giving the directional derivative of $A$ along the direction $x$. Hence, here you need *two* inputs: the *point* you are evaluating the derivative, and the *direction*. A closely related (via so called "duality") way of interpretation is probably to think $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}$ as the "$m$-tuple of matrices", where the $j$th matrix is the partial derivative of $A(x)$ with respect to the $j$th component $x_{j}$ of $x$.

The same applies to the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(AA^{T})$ with respect to $x$ and the derivative with respect to $A$.

If you are not sure what you mean by a certain symbol, then the best way to avoid confusion is to try to be explicit.

Okay, so let me give the answer. First, note that $\operatorname{tr}(AA^{T})$ is the squared sum of all entries of $A$. And let's define $\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x}$ to mean the $m$-tuple of partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x}
=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{1}} \\
  \frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{2}} \\
  \vdots \\
  \frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{m}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So we are differentiating a scalar-valued function with respect to a scalar variable, thus we are fine. As noted earlier, $\operatorname{tr}(AA^{T})$ is the squared sum of all entries of $A$, so its partial derivative with respect to $x_{j}$ is nothing but
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}2A_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial A_{ij}(x)}{\partial x_{j}}
=\operatorname{tr}\left(2A(x)\frac{\partial A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{j}}\right)
$$
Thus what you are looking for is the vector
$$
\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}A(x)A(x)^{T}}{\partial x}
=\begin{bmatrix}
  \operatorname{tr}\left(2A(x)\frac{\partial A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{1}}\right) \\
  \operatorname{tr}\left(2A(x)\frac{\partial A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{2}}\right) \\
  \vdots \\
  \operatorname{tr}\left(2A(x)\frac{\partial A(x)^{T}}{\partial x_{m}}\right)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$